# Get thumbnail image from json Android

Tags: android, json

I am getting thumbnail image from json. I have parsed json and loading thumbnail image but my App is crashing as soon as I open the App. LogCat shows `NullpointerException` in `AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader()`. I have taken reference from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/).

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_sales_return);
 private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ViewHolder holder = null;
    private Model_BarcodeDetail data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader(); // getting NullPointerException here

    public MyAdapter() {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Activity_Sales_Return.this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.table_row_sales_return, null);

                if (imageLoader == null)
                    imageLoader =    
                    AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
                 holder.thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            data = (Model_BarcodeDetail) getItem(position);
            scannedBarcode = list.get(position).getBarcode();

            }
            }
            }
```

Parsing json code:

```
public Model_BarcodeDetail GetBarcodeDetail(String api_token, String barcode) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(Utility.BASE_URL
            + "?q=webservice/pdt/barcode_detail&token=" + api_token
            + "&barcode=" + barcode + "&return=json");

    String result = "";
    Model_BarcodeDetail data = null;

    try {
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        result = httpClient.execute(postRequest, responseHandler);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject obj1 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("t2tapi");
        boolean error = obj1.has("errors");
        if (!error) {
            data = new Model_BarcodeDetail();
            data.setDatetime(obj1.getString("datetime"));
            data.setSuccess(obj1.getString("success"));
            JSONObject obj2 = obj1.getJSONObject("data");
            data.setName(obj2.getString("name"));

            data.setThumbnailUrl(obj2.getString("image"));

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Json Logcat Warning:

```
04-01 11:20:26.834: W/System.err(3844): org.json.JSONException: No value for image
04-01 11:20:26.854: W/System.err(3844):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
04-01 11:20:26.854: W/System.err(3844):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
04-01 11:20:26.854: W/System.err(3844):     at com.example.pdt.Activity_Sales_Return.GetBarcodeDetail(Activity_Sales_Return.java:3282)
04-01 11:20:26.864: W/System.err(3844):     at com.example.pdt.Activity_Sales_Return$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(Activity_Sales_Return.java:3186)
04-01 11:20:26.864: W/System.err(3844):     at com.example.pdt.Activity_Sales_Return$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(Activity_Sales_Return.java:1)
04-01 11:20:26.864: W/System.err(3844):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-01 11:20:26.864: W/System.err(3844):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-01 11:20:26.864: W/System.err(3844):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-01 11:20:26.864: W/System.err(3844):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-01 11:20:26.864: W/System.err(3844):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-01 11:20:26.864: W/System.err(3844):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Original json:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <skudetail>
      <datetime>Wed, 30 Mar 2016 07:13:26 +0000</datetime>
   <success>1</success>
  <data>
    <name>AM X COL38/44</name>
    <reference>000086</reference>
    <description>EB 3 X COL  DURA 38/44</description>
    <barcode>000086004004</barcode>
    <price>24.00</price>
    <color>NAVY S</color>
    <size>40</size>
    <stock>11</stock>
    <branch>MDT</branch>
    <supplier>KAY</supplier>
    <supplier_name>DURABLEPRESS BY KAYMANS</supplier_name>
    <location></location>
    <basesell></basesell>
    <vat>A</vat>
    <avg_cost>5.600</avg_cost>
    <last_cost>0.000</last_cost>
    <next_cost>5.600</next_cost>
    <group_code>MEN</group_code>
    <alias_code></alias_code>
    <type>TRF</type>
    <remarks1>x</remarks1>
    <remarks2></remarks2>
    <listed_days></listed_days>
    <title></title>
    <type_name>FLAT FRONT TROUSERS</type_name>
    <user1_name></user1_name>
    <user2_name></user2_name>
    <meta_keywords></meta_keywords>
    <meta_description></meta_description>
    <image>http://staging.gait-
 way.com/files/product/32106/1459320344_410cCvu-IsL._UX466_.jpg</image>
</data>

 </skudetail>
```

Comment: post the exception stack trace

Comment: You declare `AppController` as application in your manifeast...?

Comment: would you paste definition of getImageLoader() ?
make sure your AppController object is not null

Comment: @AbhishekPatel Yes I didnt add AppControler in the Manifest. In what element do I add the AppControler in the Manifest ?

Comment: Use like this  `<application
        android:name="YourPackage.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`

Comment: @SheenaTyagi Yes you have to add it to your manifest file as `<application
        android:name=".AppController"...>`

Comment: please post `AppController` class

Comment: @AbhishekPatel I added AppControler in Manifest and App is not crashing anymore, Thanks! but I am not getting Thumbnail url from json. Logcat error shows above Warning

Comment: @SheenaTyagi make sure your json object return null value or not..

Comment: @AbhishekPatel Yes I am getting null value. Am I parsing the right way? Please help :/

Comment: @SheenaTyagi please put your original json which you get from service

Comment: @AbhishekPatel Added original json.

Comment: @SheenaTyagi You will get `obj2.getString("name")` or not..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107924/discussion-between-abhishek-patel-and-sheena-tyagi).

Answer (score 1):

i think you are  wrong as you have there is **XML data but not JSON data**,,you can validate that with

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

You can use XMLDomParser to get the value in Image tag and use it as you need you can refer below link to get a reference on XML parsing

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

and also refer this it might help

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_comparison.htm

and You also might want to use [Picasso](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)(Lighter) or [Glide](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)(More Features) as it eases your worries about image loading into Views

Hope this helps